# Can't connect to SMTP from Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, smtp, azure-web-roles

I have a web role that needs to send some e-mails. I have code for this that works locally on my computer, but when I run it on Azure it doesn't work and I just get a "The transport failed to connect to the server." exception. The SMTP server uses SSL and port 465.

Is there some firewall setting that blocks this that I need to fix or could it be something else?

Comment: Where's your SMTP server hosted? Can you check if there's a firewall on the SMTP server side which is blocking the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure about the real cause for this problem, but after we upgraded to Windows Server 2012 on our Azure instances it worked.

Answer (score 1):

All outbound ports are open from Azure so any firewall issue is likely to be with your SMTP server. You could allow access to your SMTP server by opening access to all IP ranges in the Azure datacenteer your application is deployed to.

[Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn175718.aspx)

Alternatively you could use a third party solution such as [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/), which is quick and easy to setup, and depending on you usage maybe free.